# How do I choose an epsilon satisfying two conditions to show a set is open

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm asked to show the following set is open in the complex plane: {z $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$ : Re(z) > 1, Im(z) < 0}. I know how to choose my epsilon if the set had just one of these conditions, and so I tried to relate the two by choosing my epsilon to be $\epsilon$ = Re(z) - Im(z), but this doesn't seem to be the correct way to do this as I ran into roadblocks. What is the general guideline for choosing an epsilon in a situation like this, where you need to handle two properties? I tried |1-Re(z)|, but I stumbled when trying to show Im(w) < 0 for any w.

I don't want the answer, but I'd appreciate a hint in choosing my epsilon or a general tip for finding epsilon in this scenario.

Comment: Consider two $\varepsilon$'s, one for each thing you want; and take the minimum of the two, so that everything works at the same time.

Comment: Draw a picture. You need to choose a disc around $z$ so that it doesn't cross the line $\mathbb{re } w = 1$ or the line $\mathbb{im } w = 0$.

Comment: @ClementC. Oh okay, thank you. I was stuck on trying to connect the two properties, but I understand now. Can't believe how much time I wasted, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the notation $B(a,r)$ to denote the set $\{b \in \mathbb{C}:|b-a|<r\}$.

The set $U = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \text{Re}(z)>1, \, \text{Im}(z)<0\} = V \cap W$, where $V = \{z: \text{Re}(z)>1 \}$ and $W =\{z: \text{Im}(z) < 0\}$.

Say $z \in U$. Then $z$ is in both $V$ and $W$. You've already mentioned that you can find a positive $\varepsilon_1$ such that $B(z,\varepsilon_1) \subset V$, and another positive $\varepsilon_2$ such that $B(z,\varepsilon_2) \subset W$.

Consider a positive $\varepsilon$ smaller than $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2$. What can you say about $B(z,\varepsilon)$?